# How to show either spinner or animated gif on button click until message displayed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spinner, gif

From the below code, I want to display either loading spinner or any animated gif until `myMessage` should be displayed on clicking of `Submit` button on `timeout`. How can I do this, please let me know and thanks in advance !

Html:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" id="inputId" ng-model="enteredMessage" 
autofocus/>
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>
  <button type="button"  ng-click="myFunction(enteredMessage)">Submit</button>
  Entered: {{myMessage}}
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  myApp.controller('Controller',['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myFunction = function(enteredTextMessage){
      $timeout(function() {
        //I need to show the spinner for three seconds until my myMessage loading/displaying complete 
        $scope.myMessage = enteredTextMessage;
      }, 3000);
    }
  }
]);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/drr3991q/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that works. You just need to add a `ng-show` or `ng-hide` on the font awesome icon and call change the value accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
<input type="text" id="inputId" ng-model="enteredMessage" 
autofocus/>
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" style="font-size:24px" ng-show='showSpinner'></i>
  <button type="button"  ng-click="myFunction(enteredMessage)">Submit</button>
  Entered: {{myMessage}}
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.showSpinner = false;
    $scope.myFunction = function(enteredTextMessage){
      $timeout(function() {
        //I need to show the spinner for three seconds until my myMessage loading/displaying complete 
        $scope.showSpinner = false;
        $scope.myMessage = enteredTextMessage;
      }, 3000);
      $scope.showSpinner = true;
    }
})
```

Here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/691/) for demonstration as stackoverflow's code snippet is not supporting the css link to font awesome.

Comment: Glad to help you